# how to return multiple values from an asynchronous function to use in another function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

I am getting login and password values in an asynchronous function and returning using destructuring. But when I try to use the data in another function, it outputs - undefined. Help please. In what the problem

```
async function authWithLoginAndPassword() {
    const response = await fetch('');
    const data = await response.json();
    const logUser = data[0].login;
    const passwordUser = data[0].password;
    return { logUser, passwordUser }
}
submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let register = authWithLoginAndPassword();
    console.log(register.logUser, register.passwordUser)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise that resolves to whatever value you `return` from that function.  So, when you call `authWithLoginAndPassword()`, you have to use either `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from the promise that the function returns:

```
submit.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        let register = await authWithLoginAndPassword();
        console.log(register.logUser, register.passwordUser)
     } catch(e) {
        // catch errors
        console.log(e);
     }
});
```

or

```
submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    authWithLoginAndPassword().then(register => {
        console.log(register.logUser, register.passwordUser)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```